# Rotate the 360 degree image when device is tilted in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, 360-panorama

I am using [ricoh-theta-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ricoh-theta-viewer) plugin for viewing a panaroma image in 360 degree view. I could easily have a 360 degree view of the panaroma image using this library. When i touch the image, it will slide in the direction of the touch in the 360 degree view. But, i want to tilt the image when the device orientation has been changes means when user is rotating or orienting the device left, right, up or down. I tried to use below code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {RicohView} from 'ricoh-theta-viewer';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  ricohView: any;
  previousAlpha = 0;
  previousBeta = 0;
  previousGamma = 0;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", (event) => this.onDeviceOrientation(event), true)
  }

  initialize = () => {
    this.ricohView = new RicohView({
      id: "ricoh-360-viewer",
      file: 'assets/imgs/sample.jpg', rendererType: 0,
      height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth, zoom: 130
    });
  };

  onDeviceOrientation(ev) {

    if (this.canSetCameraDir(ev.alpha, ev.beta, ev.gamma)) {
      this.previousAlpha = ev.alpha;
      this.previousBeta = ev.beta;
      this.previousGamma = ev.gamma;
      this.ricohView.setCameraDir(ev.alpha, ev.beta, ev.gamma)
    }
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  canSetCameraDir(alpha, beta, gamma) {
    let canSet = false;
    let calculatedAlpha = Math.abs(this.previousAlpha - alpha);
    let calculatedBeta = Math.abs(this.previousBeta - beta);
    let calculatedGamma = Math.abs(this.previousGamma - gamma);

    if (calculatedAlpha > 40 || calculatedBeta > 40 || calculatedGamma > 40) {
      canSet = true;
    }

    return canSet;
  }

}
```

But, the problem is that, the image is being rotated using the alpha, beta and gamma of the **deviceorientation** event listener which is wrong. May be i need to manipulate the alpha, beta and gamma and then fit in the **this.ricohView.setCameraDir** function so that i can get accurate rotation of the image.

Can anyone point me out my mistake?

Comment: why dont you try destroying the previous ricoh view object and create a new one as soon as the  device orientation event is called. I am suggesting this as the window height and width dimensions are switched.

Comment: How to destory the ricoh view object and then set with events alpha, beta and gamma? Can you please direct me? I think, i am asking as when the device is being tilted or moved left, right, up or down.

Comment: is the `deviceorientation` listener being called when the device is rotated?

Comment: Yeah.. Actually it propagates so frequently with small difference in alpha, beta and gamma value

Comment: try adding `rotation: true` property to the ricoh view object in the initialisation and remove the code in device orientation listener.

Comment: setting `rotation: true`, the image rotates automatically. But, it does not rotate when device is being rotated.

Comment: are you looking for a continuous tilt in the image when the device is being rotated or a fixed rotation on device orientation change similar to the native gallery images in devices. Apologies for the repeated questions. I am trying to understand the question.

Comment: When the mobile device will be rotated or tilt in a direction, then i want the image to tilt or rotate in that direction also. Just like 360 degree view in facebook app where the image rotated or tilt with the device rotation.

Comment: Cool understood. so why dont you lock the screen orientation for the app and then pass the values directly to the 'onDeviceOrientation(ev) {
   this.ricohView.setCameraDir(ev.alpha, ev.beta, ev.gamma)
}

Comment: Did you mean to lock the screen orientation when the app opens and then call setCameraDir for every deviceOrientation event?

Comment: Is there any way without locking the screen orientation?

Comment: Sorry. Your solution does not work by locking the screen orientation. I think, i need to think about the alpha, beta and gamma. I am missing something here. Because the screen tilts when device tilts but it tilts incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Set `'orientationChange' = true` in the constructor.

That should enable the device orientation event inside package. That feature enables the gesture movement.

Comment: It is vibrating. Is there any property to set the threshold? It is flickering when the device is moving and also flickering when the device is on top of a table.

Comment: Is rotation == true for you? Try disabling it.

Comment: No. I did not set the rotation == true

Comment: The image is just flickering slightly when the device is on top of a table

Comment: this.ricohView = new RicohView({
      id: "ricoh-360-viewer",
      file: 'assets/imgs/sample.jpg', rendererType: 0,
      orientationChange: true,
      height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth, zoom: 130
    });

Comment: Interesting. I never had any issue like that. Is the flickering consistent even when orientationChange is set to `false`?

Comment: If i slide now using touch, the image is going back to the original position. But, it works fine when 'orientationChange' = false means image rotation will only works on touch. Both are not working on the same iamge nicely

Comment: No. If change orientationChange  to false. Then it is ok. No flickering. The image stays right there when i rotated using touch. But, if i change orientationChange to true, then the flickering starts. And if i rotate the image using touch, then it comes back to the original position again. But i want to stay the image where i have rotated using touch. Both touch and device rotate not working at the same time.

Comment: Alright, I guess I understand the issue and the reason for that. Let me work on that and get back to you with a fix. But with my experience while working on it, I never faced the flickering issue. Could be something with phone hardware, but yes regarding the touch functionality while deviceOrientation is true, doable.

Comment: We can stop flickering if the difference between the alpha is greater than 8 or some big number, then we will setCameraDir.

Comment: How can i give a file name to a url like "http://app.myioseum.com/img/about/History11520926960.jpg" ? It's not loading. Do i have to do anything for this?